# Do helicopters carry radar equipment? Is so, where is it placed and what type is used?

Tags: helicopter, radar

Do helicopters carry radar equipment and if so, where is it? (e.g. in the nose section like a fixed-wing aircraft).

Also what type do they use? (e.g what type of radar would a maritime helicopter carry)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most helicopter don't carry radar; there is no need for it.

In civil helicopters radar is typically used for weather detection. In most use cases there is not real need for it because helicopters are usually operating under daytime Visual Flight Rules (VFR) and are staying away from clouds. For maritime helicopters that are used in search and rescue operations or off-shore operations on oil-rigs, weather is often installed. The typical location is in a radome in the nose of the helicopter. Examples are the [Honeywell Primus 660](https://aerocontent.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/Helicopters-documents/Primus_660_Weather_Radar.pdf) or [Rockwell Collins RTA-4100](https://www.rockwellcollins.com/-/media/Files/Unsecure/Products/Product_Brochures/Radar_and_Surveillance/Weather_Radar/RTA-4100/RTA-4100-MultiScan-Weather-Radar-For-Helicopters-Data-Sheet.ashx?la=en)

Military helicopters use radar for detecting objects. Depending on the nature of the mission the helicopter is designed for, the radar is underneath (usually for navy operation, providing sea surface detection capabilities, see for example the navy version of the NH90) or on top of the rotor (to look over obstacles such a hills / trees  and provide fire control to their missiles). An example is the [AN/APG-78 longbow fire control radar](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/LONGBOWFireControlRadar/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have emphasised 'all'

Comment: :-) No worries, I'll expand my answer after I rephrase your question if that is ok by you.

Comment: Already have :-).

Comment: @sanchises Fixed, thanx!

Comment: or they hang it from the side, like the Royal Navy's (now afaik retired) AEW Seakings.