# Why does AH-64 Apache have its radar over its rotors?

Tags: helicopter, radar, ah-64

The targeting radar is above the rotor assembly !

[image: Radar]

But why ?

Comment: See [Do helicopters carry radar equipment? Is so, where is it placed and what type is used?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32157/3201), possibly a duplicate.

Comment: Because it's a good view point there.

Comment: Because this allows it to "peek over" an obstacle while hiding behind it.

Comment: Mostly so the hovering helicopter can stay below the sight line, and missile trajectory, of the enemy...[example](http://www.badassoftheweek.com/images/913892325649/ah64apache3.jpg)